# Opera producing fractional values on scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opera

This is part of a larger program which is handling a scrollbar on a `<div>` when modifying the height.

When logging the output of various values for moving the scrollbar, there's an issue occurring where values are being produced with decimal places, but only on Opera (version 44.0.2510.1449), and this is only happening on my friend's browser. On my own Opera (version 44.0.2510.1449) I do not encounter the same problem.

Though it's probably irrelevant, the purpose of the code is to find out where the scrollbar is in the div with id `#mydiv` and do something based on the result.

Similar code with changed variable names:

```
var myDivHeight = $('#mydiv').height();
$('#mydiv').height(myDivHeight + 50); //10 extra for padding
var scrollTop = $('#mydiv').scrollTop();
var scrollHeight = $('#mydiv').prop('scrollHeight');
console.log(scrollHeight + '-' + scrollTop + '=' + (scrollHeight - scrollTop));
console.log(myDivHeight + 60);
```

Note: 60 is due to the changes made to the page dynamically, so the div height has been changed. The result of the output should be that `scrollHeight - scrollTop` = `myDivHeight + 60`.

Here's my friend's console output on Opera (giving fractional scrollTop):

[image: Friend's Opera console output]

Here's my console output on Opera:

[image: My Opera console output]

Here's the console output on Chrome:

[image: My Chrome console output]

Here's the console output from Firefox:

[image: My Firefox console output]

I can't find anyone else reporting this. Has this been reported or seen by anyone else? Is there any way to overcome this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that taking the time to ask the question helped me answer it on my own.

First of all, to overcome the problem, it's a case of using `Math.round(scrollTop.value)`.

The specification for scrollTop shows it is a [unrestricted double](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-unrestricted-double) data type so Opera is handling this within spec. Reference: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrolltop

An issue where this came up in jQuery before the type was changed from integer to Number: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/608

Comment: I had to use Math.Ceil() to always round up.

Comment: `The specification for scrollTop shows it is a long data type so Opera is handling this within spec.` A long is a 64 bit integer, it is definitely not a floating-point number. Opera isn't/wasn't within spec.

Comment: Thanks @Rudey I actually wrote it wrong in this answer. I double checked the specification and it is written as unrestricted double. I've updated the answer.

Comment: In that case, I was wrong about the spec. Indeed, it says `double`.